# Flipview MVVM binding selecteditem or selectedIndex

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I am unable to get the flipview to go to the item that has been selected in my listview, it always goes to the first element in the list.

here is my flipview xaml and my page loaded code:
XAML:

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PageLoaded}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

<FlipView  
            x:Name="FlipViewItem"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ArticlesLoader.ArticleItems}"
            VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}" 
             >
            <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemsPanel> 
         </FlipView>
```

the event page loaded calls the method:
C#:

```
 private async Task LoadEverything()
            {

                if (ArticlesLoader!=null)
                {
                    Index = ArticlesLoader.SelectedIndex;

                    if (ArticlesLoader.ArticleItems.Any() 
                        && ArticlesLoader.ArticleItems.Count > Index )
                    {
                        SelectedItem = ArticlesLoader.ArticleItems[Index];
                        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
                    }

                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Index);
                }                
            }
```

what am I doing wrong? I tried setting the selectedIndex with my Index property but this this not work also.

Edit 1: RaisePropertyChanged , OnPropertyChanged are the same thing =) I am using GalaSoft.MvvmLight

Comment: is there any await call in the method LoadEverything? if not then nevermind. If so then perhaps the property changed must be run on the dispatcher thread

Comment: also what is happening in RaisePropertyChanged?

Comment: You haven't provided enough details. The buggy code is somwhere else. Maybe ArticlesLoaded is null or ArticlesLoader.ArticleItems are empty when the contitions are checked and it is loaded later.
maybe it is due the virtualization. Have you tried setting SelectedIndex rather that SelectedItem?

Answer (score 0):

Try dispatching the call to RaisePropertyChanged

```
 Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Index);
        });
```